# sizeof times constant in multiple sources

Tags: c

I am asking for your opinion on the usage of 'sizeof' when
it occurs in multiple source files and operates on the same type.
For example in my code i need

```
sizeof(float) * MY_CONSTANT
```

in several places (e.g. for memory allocation or to pass it to glBufferData() calls) and i was thinking of writing a macro for that like:

```
#define FLT_TIMES_MY_CONSTANT (sizeof(float)*MY_CONSTANT)
```

Would this bring me any benefits in terms of compilation speed? Are there any drawbacks you can think of (e.g i need one more header with that definition to be included in all the sources)?

Regards,
Alfred

Comment: Actually writing the macro would be slightly slower than doing it manually every place, considering the pre-processor has to first insert all macro values, but it's probably not gonna be anything you'll notice unless you had like a billion of those constants. You shouldn't think too much about compilation speed, you should favor maintainability over compilation speed.

Comment: If that occurs in "multiple source files" what is the trade-off between (risky) editing time and (miniscule) saving in compilation time? It's not even a good algorithm: better to use `sizeof myvar * MY_CONSTANT`.

Comment: Posting example usage of "i need

sizeof(float) * MY_CONSTANT
in several places" would garner relevant answers. IMO, using `sizeof(float)` to begin with is not optimal.  Show context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, defining `#define FLT_TIMES_MY_CONSTANT (sizeof(float)*MY_CONSTANT)` as a macro will not bring any benefits to compilation speed, and in fact, it might slightly slow down compilation speed due to Preprocessing.

Compilation occurs in 4 stages/steps:

1. Preprocessing
2. Compilation
3. Assembly
4. Linking

In the Preprocessing stage, macros are substituted with the code they represent. By defining the macro `#define FLT_TIMES_MY_CONSTANT (sizeof(float)*MY_CONSTANT)`, you are just adding in one more macro that has to be replaced throughout your code, and this adds to the work that needs to be done in the preprocessing stage. Of course, given that this is a simple replacement, the amount of time to make this replacement is probably low, but you definitely will not see a speedup.

In my opinion, you shouldn't include a macro for the sake of trying to speedup your compilation, but rather for the sake of trying to speed up development, because macros reduce the amount of time you have to spend writing out repeated code.

For more about the stages of compilation, this might be a good resource to read over: http://placementyogi.com/tutorials/c/c-basics/c-program-compilation-steps

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a micro-optimization. You should only ever manually optimize your code if it clearly provides benefits. If you find it better style to use one or the other, use the one that you prefer. You should also not be worried about compilation speed. Your primary concern should be runtime speed, which would not be affected at all by either method.

Answer (score 0):

All the macro will be replaced before the compilation process. You can use MACRO to replace function call for a little be of optimizations

`#define FLT_TIMES_MY_CONSTANT(x) (sizeof(float)*x)`

Comment: Example of a replacing function call with a MACRO
`#define MAX(a,b) ( (a > b) ?  a : b )`

Comment: `( (a > b) ? a : b )` not a good example.  `( ((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b) )` is better.

Comment: You are right, for preceding problems,but I did not want to make the MACRO looks complicated. To make the main idea is easier to be grasped.

Comment: The other problem with a macro is that the OP will soon use `MAX(i++, j++)` and then wonder why it doesn't work the same as the function he replaced.

Comment: I was under the impression that the #define directive would basically just define another constant (i don't want to replace a function). Maybe i used the term macro wrong, how would you name it?

Answer (score 0):

Packing constants definitions in new macros is a good programming practice.
It does not have any contribution to the compilation speed but rather it makes your code more readable. Macros are placed as-is into the source code after pre-compilation process.

You need to place all your shared macro definitions into separate header files and include them into those source files where they are needed.

You should be careful about **sizeof** since what it returns might change depending on the platform for which you compile. For instance, on a 16-bit microprocessor environment `sizeof(int)` returns 2 but in the case of 32-bit processors, it returns 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to be storing the returned address in a `float` pointer, I would very highly recommend this style:

```
float *buffer = malloc(MY_CONSTANT * sizeof *buffer);
```

This uses just the plain numeric `MY_CONSTANT`, while "locking" the scaling to the type of the target pointer. If you change the left-hand side to:

```
double *buffer = ...
```

it still works correctly, and nothing is hidden.